# Android graphics render quality test

Tags: android, graphics, render

I am new to this.I want to test the Render quality of graphics device.what are the parameters involved to test
   graphics render quality of any device,how can i write any app to test those parameters.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quality is pretty subjective, a kind of soulless way to go is imitate hardware vendors and look at things like fillrate (frags-per-sec) or geometry (triangles-per-sec)

Comment: Thanks for your mail.Could you point me to any links where can i use sample code to test render quality and how can i compute frags per second or triangles per second.

Comment: just write a loop that draws triangles... start out with one triangle, and note that you are running at 60FPS (16ms/frame)... increase the amount of triangles and notice your frame rate (or inversely, your time-to-render-frame)...  same with fillrate, start with overdraw (drawing a bunch of full-screen polys on top of each other)... if you want more detail, visit the imagtec POWERVR forums (assuming that is your chip) that place is pure gold.